# Visual studio 2013 yellow warning on all references in project

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a C# project with target framework set to .NET 4.5.  For some strange reason, all references are marked with the yellow warning triangle as shown below.
I have tried unloading and reloading the project.  I even tried manually re-adding one of the system references to no avail.

[image]

The warnings I get are:

> Warning   13  The referenced component 'AutoMapper' could not be found.
>     Services.Contracts Warning  14  The referenced component
>   'AutoMapper.Net4' could not be found.     Services.Contracts
>   Warning   15  The referenced component 'log4net' could not be found.
>     Services.Contracts Warning  16  The referenced component
>   'Mindscape.LightSpeed' could not be found.    Services.Contracts
>   Warning   17  The referenced component 'Mindscape.LightSpeed.Linq' could
>   not be found.     Services.Contracts Warning  18  The referenced component
>   'System' could not be found.  Services.Contracts Warning  19  The
>   referenced component 'System.Core' could not be found.
>     Services.Contracts Warning  25  The referenced component 'System.Data'
>   could not be found.   Services.Contracts Warning  24  The referenced
>   component 'System.Data.DataSetExtensions' could not be found.
>     Services.Contracts Warning  20  The referenced component
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization' could not be found.    Services.Contracts
>   Warning   21  The referenced component 'System.ServiceModel' could not be
>   found.    Services.Contracts Warning  22  The referenced component
>   'System.ServiceModel.Web' could not be found.     Services.Contracts
>   Warning   26  The referenced component 'System.Xml' could not be found.
>     Services.Contracts Warning  23  The referenced component
>   'System.Xml.Linq' could not be found.     Services.Contracts

What happened and how do I fix this?

Comment: You do have .Net 4.5 right?

Comment: Yes. Also all other projects in the solution have target framework set to 4.5 and compile fine.

Comment: Not sure how old the project is, but what versions of those assemblies are those referencing?

Comment: If I right click on any of the references and select properties, the version shows 0.0.0.0.  However, packages.config shows AutoMapper is set to 3.3.1 with targetframework set to net4.5.

Comment: Not sure if this is of any help to you, but Microsoft has documented a few solutions to fixed common issues related to broken references: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayds71se.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the suggestions in that article helped me.  I stopped there before posting here :).  Thanks anyway,

Comment: Are you using resharper?

Answer (score 34):

I had the same problem and I removed the following entry from the .csproj file and it fixed the problem for me.

```
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">  
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Enable NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Error Condition="!Exists('$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '$(SolutionDir)\.nuget\NuGet.targets'))" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Worked for me (VC2015 & Resharper 10)

Comment: Looks liek you're using solution level nuget management which resulted in a Nuget.Targets file relative to a solution (.sln) file, and your'e now trying to load one of the projects (.csproj) into a different solution. So it's failing to find the Nuget.Targets.

Comment: thanks so much, this one was really getting me

Answer (score 0):

Removing 'EnsureNugetPackageBuildImports may work but the root cause, as pointed out by @redcalx: Nuget.Targets file is missing.

I closed my solution and create a folder called .nuget
Then copied from another folder:

- NuGet.targets
- NuGet.Config

Note: in my nuget.config I have a repositoryPath node, point to c:\packages\ which helps keep all my solution's packages in one folder.

Remember, each time you start a new solution to replicate your .nuget folder.