# Referenced component "System.Runtime" could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I just randomly got that warning. That file exists on my hard drive, but VS refuses to understand it. I have no idea how to fix it, there are no solutions available online.

In the worst case scenario I will create project from scratch, but that will require moving a lot of code.

Edit

I have cloned older repository, now all references are missing. I thought that only Java has so many issues, but it appears C# is not better.

Edit 2

Rebuilding fixed all errors beside System.Runtime.

Comment: What is the full error message? Usually this kind of message is the result of a versioning problem.

Comment: @insane_developer full error is in title. Unless there are more details that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Maybe you can try the namespace `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation`. Or [edit `.csproj file`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34574735/8335151).

Comment: @KyleWang I can add other System.Runtime references, but do they contain basic System.Runtime?

Comment: @Mave12 They may have the same namespace, but not necessarily the same "basic System.Runtime". It depends on the dll you added.